# Unable to delete group without being site collection administrator

Tags: feature, site-collection, groups, impersonation

I have a Sharepoint Group (`SPGroup1`) whose owner is `User1`. `User1` has full control over the root web site (and all its sub-sites), however **it is not a site collection administrator**.

When I log in as `User1` and I try to delete the group via the site settings (http://[site collection url]/_layouts/groups.aspx) the operation fails silently, i.e., no error appears but the group is not deleted.

The group has no users in it.
I observe the same behavior when I try to delete the group in a feature event receiver running as `User1`.

Is this behavior expected ? If so, is there any way to allow User1 to delete the group without making him site collection admin ?

One solution I thought would be to, in feature code, impersonate as site collection admin and then remove the group, but I would like to do that only as a last resort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming SP2010 here...

As far as I know no one other than a Site Collection Admin can delete a SP Group.  I know it says the Group Owner can delete the group in the UI when you create a group, but I think that's either a mis-print or the assumption is the Group Owner will be a Site Collection Owner.

If you look at the privileges associated with Full Control permission level (...or any permission level for that matter), you'll notice that there is no permission for Delete Group, so this permission cannot be granted explicity.